How to change PIP mode RemoteAction button icon dynamically
I have implemented a PIP feature in my app, which is working fine and it have a button for mute & unmute. everything is working but the issue is I am not able to update the icon. can anyone please share me a peoper way to update that.
private val isPipSupport by lazy {
    packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_PICTURE_IN_PICTURE)
}

private fun setPipMode() {
    if (!isPipSupport) return
    val pipParams = getPipParams() ?: return
    enterPictureInPictureMode(pipParams)
}

private fun getPipParams(): PictureInPictureParams? {
    val rect = Rect()
    binding.rvPipMode.getGlobalVisibleRect(rect)

    val pipParams = PictureInPictureParams.Builder()
        .setAspectRatio(Rational(1, 1))
        .setSourceRectHint(rect)
        .setActions(
            getPipButtons()
        )
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
        pipParams.setAutoEnterEnabled(true)
    }
    return pipParams.build()
}

private fun getPipButtons(): MutableList<RemoteAction> {

    val callEndButton = RemoteAction(
        Icon.createWithResource(this, R.drawable.ic_pip_end_call),
        "End call",
        "End call",
        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            this, 0, Intent(this, PipReceiver2::class.java).apply {
                action = PIP_BROADCAST_RECEIVER // Use a consistent action string
                putExtra(PIP_VALUES, PIP_END_CALL) // Add any extra data you need
            }, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
        )
    )
    val isEnabled = viewModel.micEnabled.value ?: false
    val mute_un_mute_icon = if(isEnabled) R.drawable.ic_mic_on else R.drawable.ic_mic_off
    val muteUnMuteButton = RemoteAction(
        Icon.createWithResource(this, mute_un_mute_icon),
        "Mute & Un Mute call",
        "Mute & Un Mute call",
        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            this, if(isEnabled) 1 else 2, Intent(this, PipReceiver2::class.java).apply {
                action = PIP_BROADCAST_RECEIVER // Use a consistent action string
                putExtra(PIP_VALUES, PIP_MUTE_UN_MUTE) // Add any extra data you need
            }, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
        )
    )
    return mutableListOf(muteUnMuteButton, callEndButton)
}

I have tried to call setPipMode() when button is muted, but it not changing anything.
